# função para converter objeto em array não entra em loop foreach

Tags: php, php-7

Fiz a **função** abaixo para *passar* um **Objeto** de **Classe PHP** para um `array`, também **PHP**.

```
 /* Converte um objeto em array() */
  public function ObjToArray ($_obj) {

    $array = null;

    print_r( $_obj ); //funciona normalmente, imprime o objeto

    foreach ($_obj as $key => $value) :

       print "Key: " . $key . " VALUE: " .$value."<br>"; //não imprime, não entra aqui.
       $array [$key] = $value;

    endforeach;

    return $array;

  }
```

O `print_r( $_obj )` funciona normalmente.

Mas não entra no `foreach`.

Onde *estará* o erro?

Comment: Não seria mais simples converter o objeto usando um typecast?

Comment: dê um exemplo de typecast?  Fazendo a conversão na própria classe?

Comment: Seria algo assim `$meuArray = (array) $meuObjeto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Não há erro de lógica na sua função, mas se você diz que não está entrando no foreach, a razão mais provável é que as propriedades do seu objeto sejam privadas.

Uma laço foreach só acessa propriedades publicas de um objeto, a não ser é claro, que esse laço seja executado dentro de um método do seu objeto, pois um objeto pode acessar suas próprias propriedades privadas.

Então, acredito suas opções são essas

-Declare a função ObjToArray como um método na classe do seu oubjeto.

Ou

-Declare as propriedades que você quer que sejam passadas para um array como publicas.

Comment: exato. já tinha feito assim, só estava procurando  saber se existia uma função nativa que fizesse isso quando os atributos são privados